# Creating a Makefile to build swigged modules

Tags: c++, makefile, swig

I'm trying to make a module that takes .cpp and .swg files as input and creates a .so file using SWIG. The trouble is, I don't know much about makefiles, and I'm not quite sure exactly what I'm doing wrong. Here is my makefile:

```
CXX = g++
SWIG = swig
SWIGFLAGS = -c++ -python 
CXXFLAGS = -c -fpic -Wall #for debugging purposes
LDFLAGS = -shared

file_processor.so: %*.o
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^

%.o: %.cxx %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $? -o $@

%.cxx: %.swg
    $(SWIG) $(SWIGFLAGS) $<
```

When I run this, make says:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `%*.o', needed by `file_processor.so'.  Stop.
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? Can anyone suggest a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: For those of us unfamiliar with SWIG, could you describe the steps you would take if you were building `file_processor.so` by hand, without Make?

Comment: Yes, to build this file by hand I'd run the following:

Comment: 1) g++ -c -fPIC file_processor.cpp -o file_processor.o                   2) swig -c++ -python file_processor.swg  3) g++ -c -fPIC file_processor_wrap.cxx -o file_processor_wrap.o  4) g++ -shared file_processor.o file_processor_wrap.o -o _file_processor.so  A corection to the above makefile, the default target should start with _. Please note that there could be any number of .cpp files but ultimately only 1 .swg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) The default rule:**

```
_file_processor.so: %*.o
    ...
```

As written, this requires a prerequisite called "%*.o", which Make can neither find nor build. I think you meant this:

```
_file_processor.so: *.o
    ...
```

but then Make would pull in all existing `.o` files -- and not worry if any were missing. I recommend:

```
OBJS = file_processor.o file_processor_wrap.o

_file_processor.so: $(OBJS)
    ...
```

**2) The object rule:**

```
%.o: %.cxx %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $? -o $@
```

This rule won't apply unless *both* prerequisites exist, which doesn't seem to be what you have in mind. You'll have to split it into two rules:

```
%.o: %.cxx
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

(Pattern rules don't work quite the same way as ordinary rules.)

**3) Small correction:**

```
swig -c++ -python file_processor.swg
```

Did you mean `file_processor_wrap.swg`? The flow doesn't make sense otherwise, since you'd be building `file_processor.cxx` but never using it.

Comment: Thanks for catching that last one. You're right. (And for the help)